# PHPBB3/Symfony console: Arguments of command does not parsed when executed from another php script

Tags: php, symfony, console, shell-exec, phpbb

I do operate a forum using phpbb3. This version of the forum comes with an CLI tool called "phpbbcli.php". The CLI is based on the symfony/console component.

I want to use this CLI tool to add an user programmatically from within another piece of PHP code. This code is executed via an apache/mod_php call. (The user performs an registration on the website).

The command I need to call looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/forum/bin/phpbbcli.php user:add --username=test-user --password=test-password --email=mail@example.com
```

If I run this command on the shell of the server the user gets created as expected.

As I want to call this command from within another PHP Script I did the following:

```
echo shell_exec('/usr/bin/php /var/www/forum/bin/phpbbcli.php user:add --username=test-user --password=test-password --email=mail@example.com');
```

But this execution is not successful. Instead I get the error message that the username, the password as well as the email address "is too short". So the script does get executed, but the arguments "get lost" somehow.

```
[ERROR] The username you entered is too short.                                                                         
     The password you entered is too short.                                                                         
     The email address you entered is too short.
```

I already debugged the symfony/console component. The arguments are present within the console application. But the arguments do not get parsed. This should happen in the method "Command::interact".

When I execute the CLI from within the shell, the method "interact" does get called. Doing the same from within my PHP script the method "interact" is not called.

The problem occours on the production server (Ubuntu 14.04) as well as in the development environment (Ubuntu 14.04/vagrant).

I can find no reason why this is happening.